# Elasticsearch sort by text field multilanguage values inside

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have documents in a few languages. For example Russian. When I sort with text field it is not sorting with Russian letters ordering. Maybe there are some analyzers which can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the mapping for your fields...the is by default one which is non tokenized...while using sorting you can use it. like fieldName.keyword...for sorting one should use the non tokenized field

Comment: Hello, to provide some help we need your mapping, some example documents and the queries you tried so far :)

Comment: hi Guys. thank you for your response. I already solved it. it was case-insensitivity because of wrong tokenizer